# Maven/Removing timestamps from build

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-bundle-plugin

A little unusual question, probably.

I'm building apache-log4j-1.2.17 from sources, and everything works right, but I'd like to modify the process a bit and have no idea how.

Namely, I'd like to remove **Bnd-LastModified** property from manifest file and timestamp comment from **pom.properties** file. Is there any configuration that I miss? I could remove them "manually" (shell script), but that just seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem I just found the answer to the header problem on google. I realise this is a year or so late for you.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
    </archive> 
    <instructions>   
      <_removeheaders>Bnd-LastModified</_removeheaders>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was planning to compare MD5s of ZIP files to determine if I needed to upload an OSGi bundle JAR during deployment. I assumed that if the files inside the bundle JARs were the same, then the bundle JARs themselves would be the same. Between builds, I found that the timestamps you described were the only in-file differences between builds. After using shell script to pull out those timestamps -- which made all files identical -- I found that the bundle JARs were still different due to file timestamps.

I ended up comparing `unzip -lv` output for the two bundle JARs to determine equality:

```
lhash=$(unzip -lv $HOME/staging/$bundle | sed -ne '/---/,/---/p' | sed -e '1d;$d;' | awk '{L="";for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(i<5 || i>6){L = L " " $bundle}}print L}' | md5)
rhash=$(ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/keys/keyfile.pem user@$host "unzip -lv ~ubuntu/bundles/$bundle | sed -ne '/---/,/---/p' | sed -e '1d;\$d;' | awk '{L=\"\";for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(i<5 || i>6){L = L \" \" \$bundle}}print L}' | md5sum | awk '{print \$1}'")
if [ "$lhash" = "$rhash" ]
then
    different=f
else
    different=t
fi
```

My local machine is a Mac and the remote machine is running ubuntu, hence the `md5` versus `md5sum`. The `awk` nonsense is to remove the timestamps from the `unzip -l` output. After the code finishes, if `different` is `t`, then the files are different; otherwise, the files are the same.